# Выражение "Вносить представление"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Имею нечеткое понятие о выражении "вносить представление".

К примеру, президент внес представление в Госдуму о назначении на должность такого-то такого человека. Тут не понятно, кто назначает-то на эту должность, президент или Госдума. Поэтому я хотел бы уточнить это выражение.

Помогите развеять эту неясность. Объяснить значение или подберите синоним к нему. Спасибо! :)

Comment: Извиняюсь, а как тут выбрать лучший ответ?

Comment: На что кликнуть??

Comment: Под пальцем вниз есть кнопочка, её нажимаете и ответ считается засчитанным автору.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На должность назначает Госдума.
Президент официально предлагает. Это официальное предложение и называется "представлением" (обычно - если речь идет о персоналии) - сравните: "представить к награде", а процесс реализации права предлагать - внесением. Аналогично, формулировка для готового решения по персональному вопросу часто (не всегда) именуется "вынесением" (постановления, выговора). "Дума вынесла решение по представлению, внесенному Президентом". 
Синоним (частичный, на бытовом языке) - Президент предложил, поставил вопрос... Но официальный термин - именно "внес представление".

По поводу "о чем", думаю, вопросов не возникает.

Answer (score 1):

*"Президент внёс (что?) представление (куда?) в Госдуму (представление какое?) о назначении..."* Это сделал президент. Конечно, мне не очень нравится выражение *"внёс представление"*, но оно имеет место быть. Словарь Ушакова: *"Представление — 3. Письменное заявление, письменный доклад (офиц. канц.). Представление о переводе на новую должность".*